# Catching PHP variable from SQL in an array and outputting to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, sql-server

I'm trying to pass a variable into an array each time rows in an SQL database is gone through and printed onto the webpage.

Then each time an item on the page is clicked the certain variable from the field in the database is caught within a JavaScript variable so a new window pops up with the SQL field 'channel_name' as the url.

I believe I am almost there but the JavaScript variable is only holding the variable from the last SQL 'channel_name'.

I hope I am making sense...

Here is my code which goes trough the database and prints out each element:

```
  $chResult = mysql_query($chSQL);
    if ($chResult) {
        $chNum = mysql_num_rows($chResult);


    if ($chNum>0) {     
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($chResult)) {
                if ($row['is_live']=="1") {
                    $whatIsLive = "true";
                } else {
                    $whatIsLive = "false";
                }

//CREATE THE ARRAY
    $chName = array(); 


//ADD ARRAY VARS FROM CHANNEL_TITLE FIELD
    $chName[] = ($row['channel_title']);


//PRINT CHANNEL INFORMATION TO PAGE 
echo 



'<li id="'.$row['channel_id'].'" class="list-group-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-head">
                            <div class="badges">';
                                if ($row['is_live']=="1") {
                                    echo '<span class="badge-live">Live</span>';
                                }
                            echo '
                            </div>
                        </div> 

    <div class="item-image">
    <a href="'.SERVERPATH.'channels/'.urlencode($row['channel_title']).'"

  //TARGET FOR JAVASCRIPT POPUP WINDOW
    target="PromoteFirefoxWindowName"
    onclick="openFFPromotionPopup(); 


    return false;"   
    data-islive="'.$whatIsLive.'" 
    title="'.$row['channel_title'].'">';

$activeSSImage = 'userData/'.$row['user_id'].'/channelImages/ss_'.$row['channel_id'].'_t.jpg';
$defaultSSImage = 'images/ss_default.jpg';

  if (file_exists($activeSSImage)) {

    echo '<img src="'.$activeSSImage.'?rand='.rand(0, 99999999).'"         alt="'.$row['channel_title'].'" width="250" height="200">';
  } else {

         echo '<img src="'.$defaultSSImage.'" alt="'.$row['channel_title'].'" width="250" height="200">';
        }
        echo '

    <span class="image-cover"></span>
        <span class="play-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
```

The variable is then caught in JavaScript to allow the the link with channels/channel_name to popup in a new window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var theChannel = <?php echo(json_encode($chName)); ?>;
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function openFFPromotionPopup() {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("channels/"+theChannel,
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */
  }
  else
  {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
    /* else the window reference must exist and the window
       is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
       window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
       the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
  };

    console.log( "function complete" );
    console.log( theChannel );

}

</script>
```

Say I get two channels printed to the page but when I click on either of them the variable is only holding the name of the channel which was outputted last. Therefore only opening the last outputting channel window.

The effect I am trying to achieve is like what happens on http://onperiscope.com/ to give you a better idea.

I realize I may not have given enough information so please ask and I will try to give as much info as possible.

Thank you

Comment: The problem now lies with calling the array. The array is called when you click on a stream but it outputs the entire array, not just the stream you click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to pretend to have fully investigated what you are trying to do but from what you're describing is your problem simply that you are calling

```
//CREATE THE ARRAY
$chName = array();
```

for every row. When perhaps you mean.

```
if($chNum>0){
    //CREATE THE ARRAY
    $chName = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($chResult)) {
        //some code
        //ADD ARRAY VARS FROM CHANNEL_TITLE FIELD
        $chName[] = ($row['channel_title']);
```

I'd also suggest looking to use mysqli functions instead of the deprecated mysql functions

EDIT1

In response to your comment, perhaps since you already appear to including the URL for the `channel_title` in your href value, the easiest thing to do would be ditch the array and just pass the clicked object to your function and then access this property from within the `openFFPromotionPopup` function. So change your PHP to;

```
<a href="'.SERVERPATH.'channels/'.urlencode($row['channel_title']).'"
//TARGET FOR JAVASCRIPT POPUP WINDOW
target="PromoteFirefoxWindowName"
onclick="openFFPromotionPopup(this);return false;"   
data-islive="'.$whatIsLive.'" 
title="'.$row['channel_title'].'">';
```

And you javascript to;

```
function openFFPromotionPopup(elem) {
    if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
        /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
        or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */
        {
            windowObjectReference = window.open(elem.href,
            "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
            /* then create it. The new window will be created and
            will be brought on top of any other window. */
        }
```

Comment: Ahh okay great. That has fixed the array and allowed the variables to get added to the array. The array gets converted to the JavaScript variable with 

`var theChannel = <?php echo(json_encode($chName)); ?>`

However, When I click on either of the images for the streams, the variable displays both stream names, not just the one I clicked on.

I assume this needs to be caught in the <a> tag of echo so it knows which var is associated to which stream image. I am unsure on how this would work though...

Comment: @JoeyThomas I've added an edit, hopefully it will do what you need

Comment: Looking at your edit, it has worked and is a great solution, thank you!

What I did actually try was  
`onclick="openStreamPopup(\'' . $row['channel_title'] . '\');`

and in javascript

`function openStreamPopup(theChannel) {
...

 windowObjectReference = window.open("channels/"+theChannel, "window", "resizable,scrollbars,status"); 

...

}; `

which also seemed to work. But your solution does not require an array to work, so would probably be the best way to go about it. Thank you so much for the help!

Edit: Sorry I changed the named from openFFPromotionPopup to openStreamPopup.